# Add extra table using Laravel Migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-schema, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2. I have created basic tables using migration method. But now I need to add another extra table. After creating my schema, I have given `php artisan migrate` command. But it shows error like `base table or view already exists Table:Users`. I know why this happen. The migration command trying to recreate the table which already have. But I need to add another extra table in Laravel via Migration. I have gone through this https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations But I can't get any solution.

Comment: Not exactly, because the migration table contains what have been already migrated. So that migrations won't run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already executed `php artisan migrate` then next time it will give you error saying "Table already exists.".

So if you want to execute only a particular migration then either you can temporarily move all migration's php file which are executed, out of **database/migrations** folder and then execute

`php artisan migrate`

or

you can execute migration from tinker i.e. first execute `php artisan tinker` and then execute content of **up method** from the migration but without parameter type **Blueprint**.

Eg.
If following is your migration up method content

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('email')->unique();
$table->string('password', 60);
});
```

then you will have to execute

```
Schema::create('users', function ($table) {
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('email')->unique();
$table->string('password', 60);
});
```

Comment: This is what I did. Thank You

Comment: The easiest way is to move all migrations files temporarily and execute "php artisan migrate" on Local Server but, on Production Server I would recommend to execute migration through "Laravel Tinker", what method did you try, to solve your problem? @PraveenSrinivasan

Comment: Actually I have forgot to copy migration table. So it shows error. Now I followed your given answer. Now working well. Thank you @Akshay

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create another table, just create new migration and run it.

If you're trying to add columns into existinng table, use `Schema::table` instad of `Schema::create`.

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
}

Schema::table('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('description');
}
```

Comment: I have created new migration. But when I run the php artisan migrate command It said the `Base table User` is already exist

Comment: So, what are you using in a new migration `::table` or `::create`? If you're trying to create new table. Laravel tells you that table is already exist, so why are you trying to create new one?

Comment: I got the solution. The migration table is empty. So I think this will give an error.